# moving a react <div> with useRef

Tags: css, reactjs, use-ref

I am a beginner in React, and just trying to have fun re-creating an old school type of game: 'space invader'. T thought it would be a good simple exercise to work on for a beginner such as me.

I need to control a div at the bottom of the screen which will be the spaceship that will send laser beams towards the aliens above!

I am having trouble utilizing `useRef()` as a means of playing around with the position of the div.
I mean that I am trying to access the 'left' or 'right' properties of the style class the div is associated with.

The weird thing is that I can change the background color for example, or I can change the width, but I can't access the 'left' or 'right' properties to make it move.

Here is my poor humble attempt:

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-bose-ehn4f?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Are you trying to get the pad to move when the user presses the lef or right keyboard?

Comment: yes exactly ! but right now i'm just taking it a step at a time, after that i'll setIntervall the movement or something...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the css. If you want to use the left and right properties you need to have a position property set to: absolute, relative or fixed. If you put them you will be able to do it.

When you use position absolute, the container should have position relative and the left, top, right and bottom properties will appear in the context of the element with the relative position.

If you use position relative the left, right, bottom, top will be relative to the position it is supposed to be

And if you use fixed, the properties will be relative to the whole page and the element will stay there even if you scroll. And as far as I see this would be the most helpful solution

Comment: but how to access left or right of refObject.current? in order to move them. let say i want to move the div 20px left of right.

Comment: You type left: 20px; It will work only if the element has absolute or relative positions